# What's the meaning of the expression "Y a des clous, sur ton bidule !" in Barjavel's La nuit des temps?

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

Brivaux avait trafiqué un magnétophone et l’avait accouplé à l’enregistreur du nouveau sondeur. Il obtint une bande magnétique qu’il convia ses camarades à écouter. Ils n’entendirent rien, puis rien, et encore rien.

— **Y a des clous, sur ton bidule !** grogna Eloi...

Brivaux sourit.

— Tout est dans le silence, dit-il. Vous ne pouvez pas entendre les ultra-sons. Mais ils sont là, je vous le garantis. Pour les entendre, il faudrait un réducteur de fréquence. Je n’en ai pas. Y en a pas à la base. Il faudra aller à Paris.

The English translation simply omits this phrase:

Brivaux had improvised a microphone and connected it with the recording apparatus of the new instrument to produce a tape recording which he played for his colleagues. They heard nothing.

Then Brivaux smiled. "It's all in the silence," he said. "You can't hear ultrasonics. But they are there, I guarantee you that, although we would need a frequency reducer to hear them. I don't have one, and there's none at the base. Someone is going to have to go to Paris."

The German translation makes it about the scientist: »Du hast wohl Nägel im Kopf« (you've got nails in your head!) but my feeling is that the phrase is about the apparatus itself.

Comment: It is about the apparatus itself. And not only because it would be strange to call the head *bidule* (French has lots of slang word to call the head), it is the only understanding that makes sense to me.

Comment: **There's no sound at all on your thingy**! avoir des clous=to be or have nothing or zero. bidule is thingy or whatchamacallit or thingamajig. It is slang. Yes, it is about the tape recorder i.e. device. I guess the translator was clueless...

Comment: I checked English, German, Italian, Spanish, Portugese, and Russian translations. All translators were clueless!

Comment: Yes, "we" are not surprised. People really should avoid literary translation unless they have lived in a country for some number of years. People go to university and study a language and all of a sudden think they can be literary translators....

Answer (score 3):

This means:

> Il n'y a rien.

> There is nothing.

Voir [clou](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/17072).

Comment: Oui, avoir des clous c'est ne rien avoir. Mais, le bidule manque.